# How can I detect if a number is greater than 20 or greater than 50 with an if

Tags: javascript

I try to detect when a number is
 greater than 10,20,30,40, etc.
But this code does not work.

```
var number = 35;
var text;
if(number >= 10){
text = "> 10"
}
else if(number >= 20){
text = "> 20"
}
else if(number >= 30){
text = "> 30"
}
```

It only takes me the first if

Comment: Reverse the order.  Start your checks with the highest number first.

Comment: reverse the order of your options. 10 will always be less than 20 and thus it won't look further.

Comment: You can solve these types of problems by thinking about the logic a little bit and stepping through with a debugger to see what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

35 is ≥ 10. It is also ≥20 and ≥30, but you're checking for ≥10 first, so the statement within the first `if` is executed. Since the rest of the conditionals are `else if` rather than `if`, none of the others are tested.

Ideally, check for ≥30 first. Then ≥20. Then ≥10.

```js
var number = 35;
var text;

if(number >= 30){
    text = "> 30"
} else if(number >= 20) {
    text = "> 20"
} else if(number >= 10) {
    text = "> 10"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the order of the **if**'s.  The program will leave the **if/else** statement as soon as it encounters an **if** that is true, so you need to put the ones that will be false before the first that will be true.

```
if(number >= 30){
    text = "> 30"
}
else if(number >= 20){
    text = "> 20"
}
else if(number >= 10){
    text = "> 10"
}
```

This will give you the highest one it's greater than.

if you want to know all of the numbers it's greater than, you can do something like

```
text = "";

if(number >= 10){
    text += "> 10\n"
}
if(number >= 20){
    text += "> 20\n"
}
if(number >= 30){
    text += "> 30\n"
}
```

Since this isn't scalable (any number greater than 30 will just return 30), you can do something like this which will give you the multiple of 10 it's greater than

```
text = "> " + (number/10) + "0";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do the same but in a different order, beginning from bigger to little, a sort will be a good idea if it were an array.

```
var number = 35;
var text;
if(number >= 40){
text = ">= 40"
}
else if(number >= 30){
text = ">= 30"
}
else if(number >= 20){
text = ">= 20"
}
else if(number >= 10){
text = ">= 10"
}
```